# Changing Legend Labels and the alignment of the pie chart in python

Tags: python, pie-chart

Can you please help me with the following. I have a following pandas series:

```
Male: 40%
Female: 60%
```

I am building a pie chart as indicated in the code below. I want to know the following:

1. Is there any automatic way to align the graph as it is now? I was playing manually with `startangle' to come up with a "horizontal" alignment in relation to "male" and "female"
2. How can I automatically link my legend to the labels? As of now, I am manually placing `labels = ['Female', 'Male']' (first, female 2nd - male) otherwise they don't match (i.e., if I use` labels = ['Male', 'Female']'
3. How Can I get rid of 'Male' and 'Female' on the graph (I want to leave 'Male' and 'Female' just in the legend).

Thank you for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

explode = [0.2,0.02]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), facecolor='White')
ax = fig.add_axes((1, 1, 1, 1))
labels = [‘Female’, 'Male']

colors = sns.color_palette('bright')
q_1 = ax.pie(my_df,
        labels=labels,
        colors = colors,
        autopct = '%0.0f%%',
        explode = explode,
        shadow = 'True',
        startangle = 79.5,
        textprops = {'color': 'Black','fontsize':16},
        wedgeprops = {'linewidth': 6},
        center = (0.1,0.1),
        rotatelabels = 'true'),

title = ax.set_title('aaa', fontsize=16)
legend = ax.legend(title='asd', loc=1)
plt.show(q_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

let me try and answer the questions as you have posed them...

1. To keep the labels next to the wedges horizontal, you need to remove the line `rotatelabels = 'true'`. This is causing the labels to rotate.

**Pic after removing the rotatelabels field**

[image]

2. As you are using lists, the labels are to be supplied. If you create a dataframe with columns for data, labels and even colors, this can be avoided.
3. To remove the labels next to the wedges and have them only in the legend, you will need to mark the labels within the `ax.pie` as blanks and add them back in the legend using labels = ['Female', 'Male']

Both of these have been updated in the code below to showcase how it can be done.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

explode = [0.2,0.02]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), facecolor='White')
ax = fig.add_axes((1, 1, 1, 1))
#labels = ['Female', 'Male']
df=pd.DataFrame({'my_df':[0.60, 0.40], 'labels':['Female', 'Male']})

colors = sns.color_palette('bright')
q_1 = ax.pie(df.my_df,
#        labels=df.labels, 
        labels=['',''],
        colors = colors,
        autopct = '%0.0f%%',
        explode = explode,
        shadow = 'True',
        startangle = 79.5,
        textprops = {'color': 'Black','fontsize':16},
        wedgeprops = {'linewidth': 6},
        center = (0.1,0.1))
#        rotatelabels = 'true'),

title = ax.set_title('aaa', fontsize=16)
#legend = ax.legend(title='asd', loc=1)
ax.legend(title='asd', loc=1, labels = df.labels)
plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]